# Automating Maven Settings file

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have artifactory setup on our local network, and we are currently looking to put alot of our projects onto a Hudson box for CI purposes.

Currently to get a project working the user has to checkout the project they are working on, then go to their maven settings.xml file and change it. I would ideally like to streamline these procedures so when you checkout your code you can as part of the build put in the right settings file.

The project im currently refactoring has external dependencies that are pulled in through artifactory, and hudson wont build it as it cannot pull in the external dependencies...

Im still not 100% sure if this is the best course to take, but I want to remove as many manual steps as possible for project setup, and so far this seems to be a major one...

Comment: Cannot do what i'm after, so as there is no real answer will give the 1 responder the reward...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is that your pom.xml inherit from a common parent pom.xml where stuff like dependencies to some third pary repos are defined.

Comment: Its more things that go in the settings.xml that I need to set, such as Server/Mirror elements and a few other things that only seem to be allowed in settings.xml, NOT in pom files...